# Logic in JQuery, updating with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, checkbox, logic

All of my code is working properly, I'm just trying to expand it to work for all possibilities, know there must be a better way to do it, but don't think I know javascript well enough (I just started learning).

Essentially, I'm trying to call data from a database based on which checkboxes on my web app are checked. There are four boxes: "committees", "candidates", "individuals", "opinion".

My code is this:

```
if($('#committees').attr('checked')) {
    $.get("file.pl",
    {
       act: "near",
       format: "raw"
       what: "committees"
    }, NewData);
}
else {
    $.get("file.pl",
    {
       act: "near",
       format: "raw"
       what: ""
    }, NewData);
```

which works perfectly for just the committees checkbox, (the ids of the other boxes match the table name for the "what", and match the above-stated names. I want to have this work for all 4 checked boxes, without having to make huge nested statements for every possible combination of checked boxes.

I know I can list more options in the "what" category like this:

```
$.get("file.pl",
        {
           act: "near",
           format: "raw"
           what: "committees, candidates, individuals, opinions"
        }, NewData);
```

and that works, but Idk how to dynamically change that string to match which boxes are checked. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers didn't quite work unfortunately. What ended up working was this:

```
var what string = "";
$('.filters').each(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      what string = whatstring+this.id+", ";
     }});
$.get("file.pl",
    {
       act: "near",
       format: "raw"
       what: whatstring
    }, NewData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you said that your code works, I would advise that you use `.is(':checked')` instead of `.attr('checked')`:

Then you would have to assign each checkbox a class that they all would share, say `.checkbox`. And your code would be:

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $.get("file.pl",
              {
                  act: "near",
                  format: "raw"
                  what: this.id
              }, NewData);
    } else {
        $.get("file.pl",
              {
                  act: "near",
                  format: "raw"
                  what: ""
              }, NewData);
    }    
});
```

**UPDATE**

I now realize that a construct like this does need a closure in order for it to work:

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    (function( that ) {
        if($(that).is(':checked')) {
            $.get("file.pl",
              {
                  act: "near",
                  format: "raw"
                  what: that.id
              }, NewData);
        } else {
            $.get("file.pl",
              {
                  act: "near",
                  format: "raw"
                  what: ""
              }, NewData);
        }
    })( this );   
});
```

Comment: This didn't work because only the last selection of data goes through, I figured it out though, posted my answer below. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I figured as much. Glad you figure it out. The updated version may be helpful if you'd like to process all the `checkoxes` at once.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this. Use 'this' keyword.
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="file-pl" id="committees" />
<input type="checkbox" class="file-pl" id="candidates" />
<input type="checkbox" class="file-pl" id="individuals" />
<input type="checkbox" class="file-pl" id="opinions" />
```

JS

```
$(".file-pl").click(function(){
    var what = this.checked ? this.id : "";

    $.get("file.pl", {
    act: "near",
    format: "raw"
    what: what
    }, NewData);
});
```